# How to get color code of image view

Tags: android

I have an image. I need to know color of that image programatically. Does it posisble ?

Actually, I have multiple images I need to know color of image when I rotate some object.

Comment: What do you mean by "color of image"? Does it have only one color? Or for a certain pixel? Or an average value?

Comment: I want to know color of particular image by programatically. for example, if image color is red then it would be return red.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
 int ColorCode = imageView.getDrawingCache().getPixel(x, y);
```

x and y are x and y coordinates

Hope this help you

Answer (score 2):

#### For ANdroid

1. Make sure that the version specified in your dependency identifier matches your app’s compileSdkVersion, set in the build.gradle file:

```html
    android {
      compileSdkVersion 24
      ...
    }
    
    dependencies {
      ...
      compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:24.2.1'
    }
```

1. A Palette object gives you access to the primary colors in an image, as well as the corresponding colors for overlaid text. Use palettes to design your app’s style and to dynamically change your app’s color scheme based on a given source image.

   2. To create a palette, first instantiate a Palette.Builder from a Bitmap. You can then use the Palette.Builder to customize the palette before generating it. This section will describe palette generation and customization from a bitmap image

#### The following code snippet provides example methods for both types of palette generation:

```
// Generate palette synchronously and return it
public Palette createPaletteSync(Bitmap bitmap) {
  Palette p = Palette.from(bitmap).generate();
  return p;
}

// Generate palette asynchronously and use it on a different
// thread using onGenerated()
public void createPaletteAsync(Bitmap bitmap) {
  Palette.from(bitmap).generate(new PaletteAsyncListener() {
    public void onGenerated(Palette p) {
      // Use generated instance

 Palette.Swatch vibrantSwatch = checkVibrantSwatch(p);

  // Set the toolbar background and text colors
  Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
  toolbar.setBackgroundColor(vibrantSwatch.getRgb());
  toolbar.setTitleTextColor(vibrantSwatch.getTitleTextColor());
    }
  });
}


// Return a palette's vibrant swatch after checking that it exists
private Palette.Swatch checkVibrantSwatch(Palette p) {
  Palette.Swatch vibrant = p.getVibrantSwatch();
  if (vibrant != null) {
    return vibrant;
  }
  // Throw error
}
```

#### Refer This For Additional Details

#### https://developer.android.com/training/material/palette-colors.html#create-a-palette